# Solving a polynomial exponential equation

Tags: exponential-function

Is there any way to solve the following equation analytically?

$e^{ax}+bx^2+cx+d=0$

my variable is $x$ and $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ are constants.

Thank you

Comment: ok and what have you tried?

Comment: No, except for trivial cases: $a=0$, or $b=c=0$. Even a relatively simple equation like $e^x=3x$ is impossible to solve analitically.